# How can I add lines numbers (with Lineno) in the Abstract environment as defined in an Overleaf template

Tags: lineno, wlscirep

**Problem:**

How can I add lines numbers (with lineno) in the Abstract environment as defined in this [Overleaf template](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns)?

The following piece of code is the Abstract definition, which is included in the **wlscirep.cls** file:

```
\def\xabstract{abstract}
\long\def\abstract#1\end#2{\def\two{#2}\ifx\two\xabstract 
\long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces#1}
\def\go{\end{abstract}}\else
\typeout{^^J^^J PLEASE DO NOT USE ANY \string\begin\space \string\end^^J
COMMANDS WITHIN ABSTRACT^^J^^J}#1\end{#2}
\gdef\theabstract{\vskip12pt BADLY FORMED ABSTRACT: PLEASE DO
NOT USE {\tt\string\begin...\string\end} COMMANDS WITHIN
THE ABSTRACT\vskip12pt}\let\go\relax\fi
\go}
```

**My attempt:**

In the **main.tex** file I added the following code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[displaymath]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\makeatletter
\let\LN@abstract\abstract
\let\LN@endabstract\endabstract
\renewcommand{\abstract}{\linenomath\LN@abstract}
\renewcommand{\endabstract}{\LN@endabstract\endlinenomath}
\makeatother



\begin{abstract}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ....
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ....
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ....
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ....
\end{abstract}




\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}


\section*{My first section}
Here I write about .....


\end{document}
```

but I do not get the lines numbers in the Abstract. Any idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added ```\documentclass{...}```. Btw, to make everything work you/we need to use the **wlscirep.cls** file from [Overleaf template](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns)

Comment: For the sake of thoroughness, I would like to get back to you and say that I think this is out of the scope for this site. It is arguably specific and case-related. Just my 2 cents, but maybe someone else will step in.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, if this post is out of the scope for this site, where else this question should be posted ? Should I ask to a butcher or to a plumber the answer ? Please feel free to remove this post if you really think this is out of scope, otherwise please provide some hint to solve this issue. Best regards

Comment: Why are there suddenly so many questions for the `wlscirep` class? As has been discovered [already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713486/47927), this document class is not coded in an optimal way which makes certain things very difficult to change. So, if not really necessary, I suggest that you use some other document class for your project.

Comment: The answer to your question is related to the fact that the Scientific Reports journal (Nature Portfolio) uses/suggests ```wlscirep.cls``` to write the manuscript. Please see here: https://www.nature.com/srep/author-instructions/submission-guidelines. My humble opinion is that one of you masters of Latex should talk to the Editors of Scientific Reports saying what you think and try to replace that file. In general, I do not understand why the Nature Portfolio staff does not commission to one of you super skilled guys to design a new robust, flexible, and appealing template for their journals.

Comment: Oh, someone added the tag to this question! This is probably the reason it popped up =D But if I understood correctly, the editors also seem to be fine with just the `article` class, as things will probably be typeset again anyways using some other class or tools.

Comment: Why was this closed? It seems reproducible, and there is a clear answer as well. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I think the same... I also voted to re-open since a perfectly legitimate question for this forum :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot really recommend using this document class, since it defines certain things in a way that does not really allow easy amendments. Especially the defintion of the `abstract` environment is a bit peculiar.

I would suggest to redefine the `abstract` environment using a `\parbox` which would then also allow the use of line numbers:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{+b}{%
    \gdef\theabstract{\parbox{\linewidth}{\internallinenumbers #1}}%
}{}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar Baz}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle

\section*{My first section}
Here I write about ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

This has, however, an unwanted side-effect, namely if you add line numbers to the complete document as well, the abstract box will get another additional line number because it is inside a parbox (actually inside two nested parboxes).

---

On second thought, it is probably a better idea to patch `\@maketitle` directly:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@maketitle{%
        {%
        \noindent
        \colorbox{color2}{%
            \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \sffamily\small\textbf\\\theabstract
            }%
        }%
        }%
    }{%
        \nolinenumbers{%
        \noindent
        \colorbox{color2}{%
            \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \internallinenumbers \sffamily\small\theabstract
            }%
        }%
        }%
    }
    {\wlog{true}}{\wlog{false}}
\makeatother

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar Baz}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle

\section*{My first section}
Here I write about ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I  just discovered that the abstract is typeset in a parbox already ... *sigh*

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)