# How to use "chemmacros" package in Scientific Reports?

Tags: chemmacros, wlscirep

The journal of **Scientific Reports** provid a template at [Overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns#.VNzKqC7HTlM). Using **chemmacros** package will cause an error.
[image]

The error is

[image]

How should we use **chemmacros** package with **Scientific Reports**? I've found that the **chemmacros** package causes problems in many templates.

Everything can be viewed with that link, but I have post it here. The content of **wlscirep** is

```
%
% An unofficial LaTeX class for Scientific Report articles.
%
% Copyright Overleaf (WriteLaTeX) 2016.
%
% Based on the SelfArx document class.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[18/03/2016, v1.1]
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[03/11/2016, v1.2]
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[27/02/2017, v1.3]
\ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[08/08/2020, v1.4]
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage{courier}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

% Settings for the author block
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{1.5em}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}}

\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
                right=2cm,%
                top=2.25cm,%
                bottom=2.25cm,%
                headheight=12pt,%
                letterpaper]{geometry}%
                
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},%
                labelsep=period,%
                justification=raggedright]{caption}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% Set up of the bibliography style

% \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[superscript,biblabel,nomove]{cite}
%% Nov 3, 2016: Support DOI
\bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
              
%
% headers and footers
%
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{}%
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{\small\sffamily\bfseries\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%
% section/subsection/paragraph set-up
%
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries\itshape}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%
% tableofcontents set-up
%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\small\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  
  
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\bfseries\color{color1}#1.}

%
% article meta data
%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\def\@keywords{#1}}

\def\xabstract{abstract}
\long\def\abstract#1\end#2{\def\two{#2}\ifx\two\xabstract 
\long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces#1}
\def\go{\end{abstract}}\else
\typeout{^^J^^J PLEASE DO NOT USE ANY \string\begin\space \string\end^^J
COMMANDS WITHIN ABSTRACT^^J^^J}#1\end{#2}
\gdef\theabstract{\vskip12pt BADLY FORMED ABSTRACT: PLEASE DO
NOT USE {\tt\string\begin...\string\end} COMMANDS WITHIN
THE ABSTRACT\vskip12pt}\let\go\relax\fi
\go}

%
% custom title page 
%
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@title\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@author\par}
\vskip18pt%
{%
\noindent
{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\color{color1}\large\sffamily\textbf{ABSTRACT}}}
}%
\vskip10pt
{%
\noindent
\colorbox{color2}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
\sffamily\small\textbf\\\theabstract
}%
}%
% \vskip18pt%
% \noindent
% \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
% {\color{color1}\keywordname\hspace*{1em}} \@keywords%
%}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text 
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Color of section headings
\definecolor{color2}{gray}{1} % Color of the box behind the abstract
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords:} % Defines the keywords heading name

\newlength{\tocsep} 
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Show only three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text
%-----------------------------------------------
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{-\tocsep}\refname}%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
}
%% Automatically abbreviate journal names
\RequirePackage{jabbrv}
```

The main **.tex** is

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\title{Scientific Reports Title to see here}

\author[1,*]{Alice Author}
\author[2]{Bob Author}
\author[1,2,+]{Christine Author}
\author[2,+]{Derek Author}
\affil[1]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}
\affil[2]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}

\affil[*]{corresponding.author@email.example}

\affil[+]{these authors contributed equally to this work}

%\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{abstract}
Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations.
\end{abstract}
\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
% * <john.hammersley@gmail.com> 2015-02-09T12:07:31.197Z:
%
%  Click the title above to edit the author information and abstract
%
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Please note: Abbreviations should be introduced at the first mention in the main text – no abbreviations lists. Suggested structure of main text (not enforced) is provided below.

\section*{Introduction}

The Introduction section, of referenced text\cite{Figueredo:2009dg} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

\section*{Results}

Up to three levels of \textbf{subheading} are permitted. Subheadings should not be numbered.

\subsection*{Subsection}

Example text under a subsection. Bulleted lists may be used where appropriate, e.g.

\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection*{Third-level section}
 
Topical subheadings are allowed.

\section*{Discussion}

The Discussion should be succinct and must not contain subheadings.

\section*{Methods}

Topical subheadings are allowed. Authors must ensure that their Methods section includes adequate experimental and characterization data necessary for others in the field to reproduce their work.

\bibliography{sample}

\noindent LaTeX formats citations and references automatically using the bibliography records in your .bib file, which you can edit via the project menu. Use the cite command for an inline citation, e.g.  \cite{Hao:gidmaps:2014}.

For data citations of datasets uploaded to e.g. \emph{figshare}, please use the \verb|howpublished| option in the bib entry to specify the platform and the link, as in the \verb|Hao:gidmaps:2014| example in the sample bibliography file.

\section*{Acknowledgements (not compulsory)}

Acknowledgements should be brief, and should not include thanks to anonymous referees and editors, or effusive comments. Grant or contribution numbers may be acknowledged.

\section*{Author contributions statement}

Must include all authors, identified by initials, for example:
A.A. conceived the experiment(s),  A.A. and B.A. conducted the experiment(s), C.A. and D.A. analysed the results.  All authors reviewed the manuscript. 

\section*{Additional information}

To include, in this order: \textbf{Accession codes} (where applicable); \textbf{Competing interests} (mandatory statement). 

The corresponding author is responsible for submitting a \href{http://www.nature.com/srep/policies/index.html#competing}{competing interests statement} on behalf of all authors of the paper. This statement must be included in the submitted article file.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{stream}
\caption{Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
\label{fig:stream}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Condition & n & p \\
\hline
A & 5 & 0.1 \\
\hline
B & 10 & 0.01 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:example}Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
\end{table}

Figures and tables can be referenced in LaTeX using the ref command, e.g. Figure \ref{fig:stream} and Table \ref{tab:example}.

\end{document}
```

The content of **jabbrv.sty** is

```
%% 2018_02_07 - Modifications of Marie-Jean Thoraval (mjthoraval@gmail.com):
%% Suppress the end period after non-abbreviated journal titles.
%%
%% Copyright 2010 Erich Hoover
%% E-mail: ehoover@mines.edu
%% 
%% =============================================
%% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
%% of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this
%% license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is available at
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% =============================================
%% 
%% This package provides the "\JournalTitle{<title>}" command, where
%% "<title>" is a journal title that you wish to have automatically
%% abbreviated.  For example,
%%   \JournalTitle{Journal of the Optical Society of America}
%% will be replaced to read
%%   J. Opt. Soc. Am.
%% 
%% The default behavior of this package is to place a period after
%% each abbreviation.  For publications that require period-less
%% abbreviations simply include the package option "noperiod":
%%   \usepackage[noperiod]{jabbrv}
%% 
%% The default behavior of this package is to not abbreviate a
%% journal title that only contains one word.  You can disable this
%% behavior (still abbreviate one word titles) by including the
%% "oneword" package option:
%%   \usepackage[oneword]{jabbrv}
%%
%% This package also ignores undefined abbreviations (does not
%% abbreviate them) by default.  In order to make sure that all the
%% words you expect to be abbreviated are actually abbreviated then
%% include the "warnundef" option:
%%   \usepackage[warnundef]{jabbrv}
%% Please note that this option outputs a LaTeX warning for each
%% title word that does not have an abbreviation, possibly resulting
%% in a large number of warnings in the output log.
%% 
%% To change the language used for the set of abbreviations (english 
%% by default), use the  ``lang=<value>'' option with the Unix
%% language code for <value>; for example:
%%   \usepackage[lang=es]{jabbrv}
%% sets the abbreviation language to Spanish.
%% 
%% In order to add customize abbreviations this package provides
%% three additional commands: \DefineJournalAbbreviation, 
%% \DefineJournalPartialAbbreviation and \DefineSpuriousJournalWord.
%% \DefineSpuriousJournalWord simply takes a single case-sensitive
%% parameter, this parameter will be added to the list of words to
%% completely remove in the output. \DefineJournalAbbreviation takes
%% two parameters, the first parameter is the case-sensitive word to
%% abbreviate and the second parameter is the actual abbreviation,
%% for example:
%%   \DefineJournalAbbreviation{Journal}{J}
%% \DefineJournalPartialAbbreviation takes two
%% parameters juts like \DefineJournalAbbreviation; however,
%% \DefineJournalPartialAbbreviation creates an entry that matches
%% any title that begins with the first parameter, for example:
%%   \DefineJournalPartialAbbreviation{Communica}{Commun}
%% will match longer words such as ``Communications'' and
%% abbreviate any such word with the given abbreviated form. Please
%% note that care should be taken with creating custom partial
%% abbreviations, as such abbreviations that are not approved by 
%% the ISSN may match unintended title words.
%% 
%% Please note that this package is still very much in the beta
%% stage, while it should work just fine it has not yet been
%% extensively tested.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{jabbrv}[2010/08/18 v0.2
    Automatic Journal Title Abbreviation Package]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}[2006/08/17]

% Special if statement for ensuring there are no double-spaces in the resulting entries
\newif\if@gobble@space@

% Special if for warning when an abbreviation is not defined
\newif\if@warn@noabbrv@ \@warn@noabbrv@false

% Special if for if a partial abbreviation match was found
\newif\if@partial@found@

% Special if for handling exceptions to the abbreviation rules
\newif\if@abbreviate@journal@

% Special if for abbreviating when a title only contains one word
\newif\if@jabbrv@abbrv@one@word@title@ \@jabbrv@abbrv@one@word@title@false
\def\jabbrv@one@word@title{%
    \if@jabbrv@abbrv@one@word@title@%
        \journal@output@abbrv%
    \else%
        \the\temp@journal@text%
    \fi%
}

% Special definition for the period so that a double-period doesn't result at the end of the entry
\newif\if@show@period@ \@show@period@true
\newif\if@end@period@
\newif\if@no@space@ \@no@space@false
\newif\if@special@period@
\def\journal@abbrv@period@noperiod{\global\@end@period@true}
\def\journal@abbrv@period@period{%
    \if@show@period@%
        .%
    \fi%
}
\def\journal@abbrv@period{%
    \ifx\journal@char@stop\@jrnl@temp@char%
        \journal@abbrv@period@noperiod%
    \else%
        \ifx.\@jrnl@temp@char%
        \else%
            \journal@abbrv@period@period%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

% Custom ``comma below'' command (use only if \textcommabelow is defined):
\global\let\jabbrv@textcommabelow=\textcommabelow
\gdef\J@C{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname jabbrv@textcommabelow\endcsname\relax%
        \def\jabbrv@comma{}%
    \else%
        \def\jabbrv@comma{\jabbrv@textcommabelow}%
    \fi%
    \jabbrv@comma%
}

% Redefinitions for diacritical marks so that they can be processed as command names
\def\jabbrv@redefine@diacritic{%
    \def\`{@GRAVEACCENT@}%
    \def\'{@ACUTEACCENT@}%
    \def\^{@CIRCUMFLEX@}%
    \def\"{@UMLAUT@}%
    \def\={@MACRONACCENT@}%
    \def\~{@TILDE@}%
    \def\aa{@RINGa@}%
    \def\AA{@RINGA@}%
    \def\ae{@aeDIPHTHONG@}%
    \def\AE{@AEDIPHTHONG@}%
    \def\c{@CEDILLA@}%
    \def\o{@SLASHo@}%
    \def\O{@SLASHO@}%
    \def\oe{@oeDIPHTHONG@}%
    \def\OE{@OEDIPHTHONG@}%
    \def\ss{@ESZETT@}%
    \def\t{@TIE@}%
    \def\v{@CARON@}%
    \def\&{@AND@}%
    % Custom \J@C may be called directly or defined through \textcommabelow:
    \def\J@C{@JABBRVCOMMA@}%
    \let\textcommabelow=\J@C%
}
\global\let\jabbrv@graveaccent=\`
\global\let\jabbrv@accuteaccent=\'
\global\let\jabbrv@circumflex=\^
\global\let\jabbrv@umlaut=\"
\global\let\jabbrv@macronaccent=\=
\global\let\jabbrv@tilde=\~
\global\let\jabbrv@ringa=\aa
\global\let\jabbrv@ringA=\AA
\global\let\jabbrv@aediphthong=\ae
\global\let\jabbrv@AEdiphthong=\AE
\global\let\jabbrv@cedilla=\c
\global\let\jabbrv@slasho=\o
\global\let\jabbrv@slashO=\O
\global\let\jabbrv@oediphthong=\oe
\global\let\jabbrv@OEdiphthong=\OE
\global\let\jabbrv@eszett=\ss
\global\let\jabbrv@tie=\t
\global\let\jabbrv@caron=\v
\global\let\jabbrv@and=\&
% Custom:
\global\let\jabbrv@comma=\J@C
% When outputing abbreviations or un-abbreviated words the diacritic match
% list should be disabled (return things to normal):
\def\jabbrv@normal@diacritic{%
    \let\`=\jabbrv@graveaccent%
    \let\'=\jabbrv@accuteaccent%
    \let\^=\jabbrv@circumflex%
    \let\"=\jabbrv@umlaut%
    \let\==\jabbrv@macronaccent%
    \let\~=\jabbrv@tilde%
    \let\c=\jabbrv@cedilla%
    \let\aa=\jabbrv@ringa%
    \let\AA=\jabbrv@ringA%
    \let\ae=\jabbrv@aediphthong%
    \let\AE=\jabbrv@AEdiphthong%
    \let\o=\jabbrv@slasho%
    \let\O=\jabbrv@slashO%
    \let\oe=\jabbrv@oediphthong%
    \let\OE=\jabbrv@OEdiphthong%
    \let\ss=\jabbrv@eszett%
    \let\t=\jabbrv@tie%
    \let\v=\jabbrv@caron%
    \let\&=\jabbrv@and%
    % Custom \J@C may be called directly or defined through \textcommabelow:
    \let\J@C=\jabbrv@comma%
    \let\textcommabelow=\jabbrv@comma%
}

% Define Common Abbreviations (see language definition files for the list):
\providecommand{\DefineJournalAbbreviation}[2]{
    \begingroup
        \jabbrv@redefine@diacritic
        \expandafter\gdef\csname journal@abbrv@#1\endcsname{%
            \begingroup%
                \jabbrv@normal@diacritic%
                #2%
            \endgroup%
            \@gobble@space@false%
            \journal@abbrv@period%
        }
    \endgroup
}

% Define specific journals that are exceptions:
\providecommand{\DefineJournalException}[2]{
    \begingroup
        \jabbrv@redefine@diacritic
        \expandafter\gdef\csname journal@exception@#1\endcsname{%
            \begingroup%
                \jabbrv@normal@diacritic%
                #2%
            \endgroup%
            \@gobble@space@false%
        }
    \endgroup
}

% Define Common Partial Abbreviations (see language definition files for the list):
\providecommand{\DefineJournalPartialAbbreviation}[2]{
    \begingroup
        \jabbrv@redefine@diacritic
        \expandafter\gdef\csname journal@partial@abbrv@#1\endcsname{%
            \begingroup%
                \jabbrv@normal@diacritic%
                #2%
            \endgroup%
            \@gobble@space@false%
            \journal@abbrv@period%
        }
    \endgroup
}

% Define Suprious Word Removal:
\providecommand{\DefineSpuriousJournalWord}[1]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname journal@abbrv@#1\endcsname{\journal@output@space}%
}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{of}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{in}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{and}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{the}

% Handle the rather generic \futurelet code:
\newtoks\temp@journal@text
\newtoks\temp@journal@text@
\temp@journal@text{}
\def\journal@char@stop{}
\def\@journal@space{\afterassignment\@journal@space@\let\@tempa= }
\def\@journal@space@{\journal@char@loop}
\def\@journal@gobble#1{\journal@char@loop}
\def\@journal@character#1{%
    \temp@journal@text\expandafter{\the\temp@journal@text#1}%
    \journal@char@loop%
}
\def\journal@char@loop{%
    \futurelet\@jrnl@temp@char%
    \journal@char@loop@%
}

% Code for finding the length of a string:
\newcounter{jabbrv@strlen@count}
\def\jabbrv@strlen@stop{}
\def\jabbrv@strlen#1{%
    \setcounter{jabbrv@strlen@count}{1}%
    \expandafter\jabbrv@strlen@ #1\jabbrv@strlen@stop%
}
\def\jabbrv@strlen@#1{%
    \@ifnextchar\jabbrv@strlen@stop%
    {}%
    {%
        \addtocounter{jabbrv@strlen@count}{1}%
        \expandafter\jabbrv@strlen@%
    }%
}

% The following ``for loop'' command is a convenience function for going over the word's characters
\newcommand{\jabbrv@for@loop}[5][1]{%
    \setcounter{#2}{#3}%
    \ifnum#4\relax%
        #5%
        \addtocounter{#2}{#1}%
        \jabbrv@for@loop[#1]{#2}{\value{#2}}{#4}{#5}%
    \fi%
}

% Gobble a given number of characters off the end of a string
\newcounter{jabbrv@gobble@temp}
\def\jabbrv@gobble@stop{}
\def\jabbrv@gobble@ending#1#2#3{%
    \setcounter{jabbrv@gobble@temp}{#3}%
    \addtocounter{jabbrv@gobble@temp}{-#2}%
    \temp@journal@text@{}%
    \expandafter\jabbrv@gobble@ending@ #1\jabbrv@gobble@stop%
}
\def\jabbrv@gobble@ending@#1{%
    \expandafter\ifnum\value{jabbrv@gobble@temp} > 0\relax%
        \temp@journal@text@\expandafter{\the\temp@journal@text@#1}%
    \fi%
    \@ifnextchar\jabbrv@gobble@stop%
    {}%
    {%
        \addtocounter{jabbrv@gobble@temp}{-1}%
        \expandafter\jabbrv@gobble@ending@%
    }%
}

% Find partial title word matches
\newcounter{jabbrv@loop@i}
\newcounter{jabbrv@loop@max}
\def\journal@output@abbrv@partial{%
    \@partial@found@false%
    \jabbrv@strlen{\the\temp@journal@text}%
    \setcounter{jabbrv@loop@max}{\value{jabbrv@strlen@count}}%
    \jabbrv@for@loop{jabbrv@loop@i}{0}{\value{jabbrv@loop@i} < \value{jabbrv@loop@max}}{%
        \jabbrv@gobble@ending{\the\temp@journal@text}{\value{jabbrv@loop@i}}{\value{jabbrv@loop@max}}%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname journal@partial@abbrv@\the\temp@journal@text@\endcsname\relax%
            % No known partial abbreviation
        \else%
            \@partial@found@true%
            \csname journal@partial@abbrv@\the\temp@journal@text@\endcsname%
            \setcounter{jabbrv@loop@i}{\value{jabbrv@loop@max}}%
        \fi%
    }%
}

% Output single spaces even when there are multiple spaces together
\def\journal@output@space{%
    \if@gobble@space@%
    \else%
        \space%
        \@gobble@space@true%
    \fi%
}

% Output the correct abbreviation for a title word
\def\journal@output@abbrv{%
    \if@special@period@%
        \journal@abbrv@period%
    \else%
        \if@no@space@%
            .% There was a user-entered period with no space after it
        \else%
            \journal@output@space%
        \fi%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname journal@abbrv@\the\temp@journal@text\endcsname\relax%
            \journal@output@abbrv@partial%
            \if@partial@found@%
                % Partial match was output, do nothing.
            \else%
                % No known abbreviation
                \if@warn@noabbrv@%
                    \@latex@warning{No abbreviation defined for `\the\temp@journal@text'}%
                \fi%
                \begingroup%
                    \jabbrv@normal@diacritic%
                    \the\temp@journal@text%
                \endgroup%
                \global\@end@period@false % reset the "need a period at the end" indicator
                \@gobble@space@false%
            \fi%
        \else%
            % Replace with abbreviation
            \expandafter\csname journal@abbrv@\the\temp@journal@text\endcsname%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \@special@period@false%
}

% Allow us to keep track of the number of words in an abbreviation so that when there's only one we can choose not to abbreviate
\newcounter{jabbrv@word@count}
\def\jabbrv@reset@word@count{%
    \setcounter{jabbrv@word@count}{0}%
}
\def\jabbrv@step@word@count{%
    \addtocounter{jabbrv@word@count}{1}%
}

% Loop through the \futurelet characters finding title words to replace
\def\journal@char@loop@{%
    % The space character is the ``special token'' - use this character to find
    % title words to abbreviate
    \ifx \@sptoken\@jrnl@temp@char%
        \journal@output@abbrv%
        \jabbrv@step@word@count%
        \temp@journal@text{}%
        \@no@space@false%
        \let\@tempa\@journal@space%
    \else%
        % \journal@char@stop is specially defined so this routine knows
        % when the entire text has been read (where to stop)
        \ifx \journal@char@stop\@jrnl@temp@char%
            \expandafter\ifnum\value{jabbrv@word@count} > 0\relax%
                \journal@output@abbrv%
            \else%
                \jabbrv@one@word@title%
            \fi%
            \let\@tempa\@gobble%
        \else%
            % Measure all other characters and include them in the title word
            \@special@period@false%
            \let\@tempa\@journal@character%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \@tempa%
}

% Eat a period at the end of the entry if the next character is also a period
\def\@jrnl@eat@period#1{%
    \if@end@period@%
        \ifx.#1\else%
            \ifx\newblock#1%
                .\newblock%
            \else%
                \journal@abbrv@period@period%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    #1%
}

% Skip groups after the \JournalTitle command
\def\@jrnl@eat@period@groupskip{%
    \@ifnextchar\egroup%
    {\@jrnl@eat@period@groupskip@}%
    {\@jrnl@eat@period}%
}
\def\@jrnl@eat@period@groupskip@{%
    \egroup \expandafter\@jrnl@eat@period\bgroup%
}

% Call \journal{<title>}, where <title> is the title for which
% journal abbreviation replacements should be performed.
\providecommand{\JournalTitle}[1]{%
    \@abbreviate@journal@true%
    \global\@end@period@false%
    \begingroup%
        \jabbrv@redefine@diacritic%
        \edef\journal@fulltitle{#1}%
        \ifcsname journal@exception@#1\endcsname%
            \csname journal@exception@#1\endcsname%
            \global\@abbreviate@journal@false%
        \fi%
    \endgroup%
    \if@abbreviate@journal@%
        \begingroup%
            \@gobble@space@true%
            \@special@period@false%
            \jabbrv@redefine@diacritic%
            \jabbrv@reset@word@count%
            \expandafter\journal@char@loop%
                #1%
            \journal@char@stop%
        \endgroup%
    \fi%
    % If the next character is not a period then add one in
    % if the last character would have been a period
    \@jrnl@eat@period@groupskip%
}

% Declare an option for disabling periods
\DeclareVoidOption{noperiod}{\@show@period@false}

% Declare an option for abbreviating one word titles
\DeclareVoidOption{oneword}{\@jabbrv@abbrv@one@word@title@true}

% Declare an option for enabling undefined abbreviation warnings
\DeclareVoidOption{warnundef}{\@warn@noabbrv@true}

% Declare an option for the default abbreviation list
\gdef\jabbrv@lang{en}
\define@key{jabbrv}{lang}{\gdef\jabbrv@lang{#1}}

% Process the option list and input the language definitions
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{jabbrv}
\InputIfFileExists{jabbrv-ltwa-all.ldf}{}{%
    \@latex@error{The master abbreviation language file `jabbrv-ltwa-all.ldf' was not found}{Make sure the file is in the appropriate folder and recompile.}%
}
\InputIfFileExists{jabbrv-ltwa-\jabbrv@lang.ldf}{}{%
    \@latex@error{Abbreviation language `jabbrv-ltwa-\jabbrv@lang.ldf' not found}{Select a valid language and recompile.}%
}
```

All the content can be downloaded at [permalink](https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.25439371.v1)

Comment: Please never just show an image of your code, no-one want to retype it. Where does one get that class (`wlscirep`)? It is not a standard one. Without it one cannot debug.

Comment: Why do you think it‘s used differently? Please add this to your question, besides code.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your kind reply. I have updated my question.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks. I have updated my code.

Comment: 'Templates' are generally poor quality. I don't know why calling your class a 'template' is correlated with poor quality, but this one is no exception. No class should load `lipsum`. No LaTeX code should use obsolete font commands. What is `\textbf\\` supposed to do? It is also loading `hyperref` too early for it to work properly. ...

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File \`jabbrv.sty' not found.`

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your kind reply. I have updated all contents here.

Comment: Thank you. Hm, files are there now (links may disappear in future). However, you ask an open question (how) and did not describe a specific problem. I don’t see any effort to boil down your main.tex to pinpoint and demonstrate a specific problem with chemmacros. So, there‘s little we can do here.

Comment: ``LaTeX Error: The master abbreviation language file `jabbrv-ltwa-all.ldf' was not found.`` + ``LaTeX Error: Abbreviation language `jabbrv-ltwa-en.ldf' not found.`` + typo in `\usepakcage{chemmacros}` (should be `\usepackage{chemmacros}`) + ``LaTeX Error: File `stream' not found.``

Comment: @cabohah The problem still exists if you comment out `\RequirePackage{jabbrv}` in `wlscirep.cls` (last line). Thus, it seems unrelated. But I find it difficult to identify the culprit. If I comment out the `abstract` environment from main `.tex` file, the errors disappear.

Comment: It seems that the defintion of the `abstract` environment in `wlscirep.cls` is faulty, but I don't know the exact cause. You can solve the issue by placing `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{+b}{\gdef\theabstract{#1}}{}` in the preamble in your document.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Just a note: If the journal uses a very, very old LaTeX their `abstract` definition could work and the `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` could fail (because of missing `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` in old LaTeX kernels). Nevertheless I agree, that the `abstract` definition in the class breaks something and should be changed. I would recommend to report the issue to the template maintainer resp. the journal. Alternatively, loading `xparse` could help to make the document work also with very old LaTeX kernels.

Comment: @cabohah You are totally right. However, if they really use an old version of LaTeX, things are even more complicated, because we don't know which (if any) version of `chemmacros` they use and things would be even more likely to break. So, in this case it would really be best to consult the journal editors.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks for your kind reply. I have corrected **\usepakcage{chemmacros}**.

Comment: @JasperHabicht `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{+b}{\gdef\theabstract{#1}}{}` would cause nothing to output.

Comment: @cabohah **I would recommend to report the issue to the template maintainer resp. the journal.** They would not care about this. I have raised several issues in the past, but none of them were resolved in the end.

Comment: @Y.zeng You need to place it in your preamble, for example right before `\usepackage {chemmacros}`. If it does not work as expected: Do you get any error?

Comment: I would place it immediately after `\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}` to correct the definition as early as possible.

Comment: @Y.zeng If the (unofficial) template is unmaintained, just don't use it. Unmaintained templates are doomed from the outset to fail horribly and plunge the user into chaos.

Comment: @cabohah I'm sorry, I made a mistake with the template. `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{+b}{\gdef\theabstract{#1}}{}` works well. Basically no journal will respond to latex questions.

Comment: @Y.zeng There are journals/publisher with officially maintained classes/templates. But unofficial templates at overleaf are unfortunately often completely unmaintained and I would always try to avoid using such templates.

Comment: @cabohah I have contacted the official LaTeX maintenance teams of AGU and Springer in the past. Either they did not respond or they informed me that they would try to fix the issue. However, the problem was never resolved in any of the instances. This template is provided by the **Scientific Reports** on Overleaf, and it is also the official template on the journal's website. They have a collaboration with Overleaf.

Comment: @Y.zeng If it is official, they should change: “`% An unofficial LaTeX class for Scientific Report articles.`” Otherwise it is officially unofficial. ;-) Furthermore, they should not offload support onto the community. :(

Comment: @cabohah Very weird. From **Scientific Reports**, https://www.nature.com/srep/author-instructions/submission-guidelines#texlatex-files , it says **If you’re submitting LaTeX files, you can either use the standard ‘Article’ document class (or similar) or the wlscirep.cls file and template provided by Overleaf.** But it is unofficial?

Comment: So I would use the standard `article` class, because it is the best maintained class ever.

Comment: @cabohah I will consider this suggestion because the template is too poor in quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place `\begin{document}` before

```
\title{Scientific Reports Title to see here}
```

(where it generally belongs, in my opinion).

Since `chemmacros` is doing business at begin document, the (horrible) definition of `\abstract` in the class breaks a lot of things.

---

Let's try and see what happens. In the class we find

```
\def\xabstract{abstract}
\long\def\abstract#1\end#2{\def\two{#2}\ifx\two\xabstract
\long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces#1}
\def\go{\end{abstract}}\else
\typeout{^^J^^J PLEASE DO NOT USE ANY \string\begin\space \string\end^^J
COMMANDS WITHIN ABSTRACT^^J^^J}#1\end{#2}
\gdef\theabstract{\vskip12pt BADLY FORMED ABSTRACT: PLEASE DO
NOT USE {\tt\string\begin...\string\end} COMMANDS WITHIN
THE ABSTRACT\vskip12pt}\let\go\relax\fi
\go}
```

Now, suppose we have

```
\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
```

As usual, LaTeX does a few things, among which `\begingroup` and eventually issues `\abstract`. With the given definition, everything up to the first `\end` including the following token or braced group of tokens is absorbed. What's before `\end` becomes `#1` and the token or braced group following `\end` becomes `#2`, so we get (where `•` denotes a space token and irrelevant parts are abbreviated as `...`; here endlines are not to be taken into considerations)

```
\def\two{abstract}
\ifx\two\xabstract
\long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces•Text•}•
\def\go{\end{abstract}}
\else
\typeout{...}•Text•\end{abstract}•
\gdef\theabstract{...}\let\go\relax
\fi
\go
```

The conditional turns out to be true, so we end up with

```
\long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces•Text•}•
\def\go{\end{abstract}}
\else...\fi
\go
```

The definitions are carried out, the trailing space token is ignored because TeX is in vertical mode. All tokens from `\else` up to `\fi` are skipped and we remain with `\go` that expands to

```
\end{abstract}
```

Here's what creates the problem! Indeed `\end{abstract}` issue `\endabstract` ***which has a standard definition***, namely

```
\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi
```

Now we can look at `\endquotation` that does thing expecting that a list had been opened (with `\quotation`). This causes havoc.

The class should do `\let\go\endgroup` instead of `\def\go{\end{abstract}}`.